# Javascript: .push is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having a problem with my code:

```
var arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]];
console.log(reduce(arrays,function(array,b){
  return array.push(b);
}));

function reduce(array,combine){
  var current = [];
  for(var i = 0;i<array.length;i += 1){
    current = combine(current,array[i]);
  }
  return current;
}
console.log(reduce([1, 2, 3, 4], function(array, b) {
  return array.push(b);
}));

// → [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: array.push is not a function (line 3)
```

As far as I understand, this is because it is treating the array argument as something other than an array. However, I thought I fed it the variable "current" which is an array. Can someone explain the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, just caught that.  Thanks.

Comment: why don't you use the built-in [].reduce() ?

Comment: @dandavis I suspect he's using this as an exercise to learn how to write higher-level functions.

Comment: `array.push` returns the next available `index`, and you cannot use `push` on Number

Comment: Do you realize you can do something like this: `var flattened = [].concat.apply([],arrays)` to get the same result?

Comment: You have all of this logging, but the most useful place would've been `console.log(array)` in that first reduce() call, as that variable and the .push() against it is where you're getting this error.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`Array.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) doesn't return an array.  It returns the *new* length of the array it was called on.

So, your `return array.push(b);` returns an `int`.  That int gets passed back as `array`... which is not an array so it doesn't have a `.push()` method.

You need to do:

```
array.push(b);
return array;
```

Answer (score 3):

Return just the Array, see below:

http://jsfiddle.net/0en82r7t/1/

```
var arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]];
console.log(reduce(arrays,function(array,b){
  array.push(b);
  return array;
}));

function reduce(array,combine){
  var current = [];
  for(var i = 0;i<array.length;i += 1){
    current = combine(current,array[i]);
  }
  return current;
}
console.log(reduce([1, 2, 3, 4], function(array, b) {
  array.push(b)
  return array;
}));
```

> array.push does not return an Array, but instead the new length

Also, I know this is just a test, but in the future and in real app development don't name an `Array` array. Use more verbose and clear naming, examples: numGroupArray, datesArray, timeArray, tagsArray...

Comment: I believe naming it as `array` is just a personal preference.

Comment: Yep, array.push() returns the length of the array, so when combine gets called on the next iteration, current is no longer set to an array but an int.

Comment: Although, this will solve the problem, please explain what is causing the problem, so that OP or any other user reading this will not ask the same question again

Comment: thanks man, I didn't realize returning array.push did that. can't believe I didn't catch an easy mistake like that.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that `array.push(b)` returns the new length of the `array`. So after calling `combine(current, array[i])` for the first time, the length of your array will be returned and `current` becomes an `integer`, and since `current` is the passed to `combine(current, array[i])` in the next iteration, JavaScript throws the `TypeError`. Your implementation for `combine(current, array[i]` should look like this:

```
function(array, b) {
    array.push(b);
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ES6 solution :

```
reduce([1, 2, 3, 4], (array, b) => [...array, b], [])
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what the function reduce is doing, but the problem is that Array.prototype.push returns the length of the array.

```
var array = [1,2,'b'];
var val = array.push('foo');
// val === 4;
```

Therefore, instead of re-setting current every iteration of your loop, just simply call the function since `.push()` modifies the array in place.

```
function reduce(array,combine){
  var current = [];
  for(var i = 0;i<array.length;i += 1){
    combine(current,array[i]);
  }
  return current;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a problem in your implementation:

```
function(array, b) {
  return array.push(b);
}
```

What you are returning from this function is not a array.

```
return array.push(b);
```

returns the length of the array after performing the push.

So, you should modify your function to:

```
function(array, b) {
  array.push(b);
  return array;
}
```

This might do the trick. Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old and practically already solved, but It didn't solve my issue directly. When searching for solutions I discovered another way to go `avoid .push()` method if we wanted to directly return the array.

```
return [ ...array, b];
```

as explained in this video at 1:41:00
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oBt53YbR9Kk&t=199s